# Disposition of HTML-Select having UTF-Icons

Tags: html, google-chrome, utf-8, symbols

Having this HTML

```html
<select>
 <option>Foo</option>
</select>

<select>
 <option>Foo</option>
</select>
```

The secodn input is dispositioned. How to avoid this effect?

Comment: It hasn't dispositoned. It arranged itself according to the content available.

Answer (score 3):

The UTF character is taller than the text, so it is displacing the select box.

I've added a bit of CSS to fix it - `vertical-align: middle` to line the select boxes up with each other; and `line-height: 1.75em` to make the character visible.

```css
select {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 1.75em;
}
```

```html
<select>
 <option>Foo</option>
</select>

<select>
 <option>Foo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```css
select {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<select>
 <option>Foo</option>
</select>

<select>
 <option>Foo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue with the disposition of the two select elements. The trick was to give them `position:relative;` and `float:left;` which you can confirm by removing the `height` and `margin-right` and re-running:

```css
.lineEmUp
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  height:28px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<select class="lineEmUp">
  <option>Foo</option>
</select>

<select class="lineEmUp">
  <option>Foo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <select>
         <option>Foo</option>
         <option>☂Bar</option>
       </select>

      <select>
       <option>Foo</option>
       <option>Bar</option>
      </select>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you. The displacement seems to be still existing.